# scala: whether the following two are the same

Tags: scala, function-literal

Code piece 1

```
maps foreach { case (k, v) =>
  // do something
}
```

code piece 2:

```
maps foreach { 
  case (k, v) => {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I am new to scala. Just wonder whether the above two pieces of codes are the same or not? which one is better?

Thanks

Comment: They are the same in this instance (only one case). I personally like the first better if there's only one case, the second if there's more than one.

Comment: I prefer the first one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those two pieces of code are same.

But unfortunately none of them takes into account the recommendations of the [Scala style guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/).

1. Omitting dots and using spaces [is not recommended](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html).
2. [Always omit braces in `case` clauses](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html).
3. `case` may be present on same line or on the next line: it depends on the contents of `// do something`.

So the original code should be formatted as

```
maps.foreach {
  case (k, v) => // do something
}
```

Comment: as for point 3, you mean `case (k, v) =>` and `// do something` may be on the same line?

Comment: Yes, everything in this example may be on the same line, if `// do something` is short and concise.